# Internet browsing freezes on other LAN PCs when my computer NIC cable is plugged in

Tags: networking, browser, freeze, network-adapter, rj-45

The last two months in pain, confusion and searching, first of all I need to tell you that I really cannot wording my question, even before posted it here I couldn't asks for a friend's help because I really don't know how to ask it…

So, let me tell you the story:
I'm working in a company and we have a set of computers connected through a LAN and they are sharing the same internet connection, we usually use these PCs to access a mother company's VPN to operate an **Oracle Forms Server application**.

The problem is, sometimes other computers in my network complain of internet browsing freezing, their browsers doesn't load webpages 100%, instead, the page loads most of its elements and then stops and the loading indicator of the browser is still running, they have tried many websites and the problem still the same.. BUT on the other hand –on their computers- the **Oracle Forms Server application** is still working perfectly, it's just all about browsing!!

**THE SURPRISE IS:** when I unplug my PC's network cable every other computer run perfectly in browsing and vice versa!!!

So why is that?? Needless to say that all of my applications on my PC is not weird it's all normal applications like MS Office, browsers and VPN tools.

**PS:** I have an application that may look like suspicious, it is [**WinPcap**](https://www.winpcap.org/) and I use it to control network bandwidth, but when the problem happens it is off…

**Additional info:** I replaced my computer two times with new computers and the problem is still exist.